# PEAR gives no output from CLI

Tags: php, macos, osx-lion, pear, mamp

I am trying to run

> /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.3/bin/pear

From Terminal on Mac OS X Lion. I get no output, using `-h`, `-v`, `-V` and `version` do not give any output either.

There are also no errors.

I am running MAMP on Mac OS X Lion, both are clean installs.

**Slightly off topic**

I am at my whits end on this, at **no point** has PEAR ever worked first time or felt like something I can trust as a platform to reliably get/update libraries. Why on earth is it even still around? It also seems to be a requirement for installing things like Phing correctly for newer libraries like Propel ORM.

Getting Propel working is my ultimately goal. But why oh why do I have to use PEAR still, its old and rubbish!

Thanks for any help,
Jake

Comment: I, for one, never installed propel from pear. Downloaded the tarball, unpacked and was happy with it. You should also check out [composer](http://getcomposer.org/) the new rockstar for php dependency management.

Comment: This isn't for all of Propel, it's reverse functionality needs Phing, which should be installed from PEAR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error but it is not displayed.
Make sure in your php.ini you have the following settings:

```
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL
```